# Inserting or Updating a table with 2 sub queries in SQL Server

Tags: sql, t-sql, subquery

I am having a hard time doing a 'INSERT INTO' with 2 sub queries in the WHERE clause.  I'm not sure wht I'm missing, it keep stating that an expression of non-boolean type specified in context where a condition is expected, near ';'.

This is my attempt at it:

```
INSERT INTO [Monitor].[dbo].[MonitorIncidents]
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.MonitorSource
WHERE (
    SELECT DISTINCT * 
    FROM Lookup.dbo.ServerInfo S 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1  
        FROM Lookup.dbo.Facts F 
        WHERE F.FactsName = S.SrvName 
        AND W.DateTime > DATEADD(hour, -23, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    )
)
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant to use `where exists ( select distinct *...)` (or `where not exists`)

Comment: And where is `W` defined? You have a `W.DateTime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `WHERE` clause is missing an operand like `=`,`<`, `>`, etc. You are just returning a field to `WHERE` wihout a comparison. Depending on what you want to do, extend your `WHERE` to include a comparison.